# Spark thrift server use only 2 cores

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-dataproc

Google dataproc one node cluster, VCores Total = 8. I've tried from user spark:

```
/usr/lib/spark/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 4
```

tried to change /usr/lib/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf

tried to execute

```
   export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=6
   export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
```

before start-thriftserver.sh

No success. In yarn UI I can see that thrift app use only 2 cores and 6 cores available.

UPDATE1:
environment tab at spark ui:

```
spark.submit.deployMode client
spark.master    yarn
spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors    6
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors    10000
spark.executor.cores    4
spark.executor.instances    1
```

[image: yarn ui]
[image: spark ui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what yarn mode is that app in.
Can be `yarn client` - 1 core for Application Master(the app will be running on the machine where you ran command `start-thriftserver.sh`).
In case of `yarn cluster` - Driver will be inside AM container, so you can tweak cores with `spark.driver.cores`. Other cores will be used by executors (1 executor = 1 core by default)
Beware that --num-executors 2 --executor-cores 4 wouldn't work as you have 8 cores max and +1 will be needed for AM container (total of 9)
You can check cores usage from Spark UI - http://sparkhistoryserverip:18080/history/application_1534847473069_0001/executors/

Options below are only for Spark standalone mode:

```
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=6
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
```

Please review all configs here - [Spark Configuration (latest)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

In your case you can edit spark-defaults.conf and add:

```
spark.executor.cores 3
spark.executor.instances 2
```

Or use local[8] mode as you have only one node anyway.

Comment: I've tried to reduce num-executers to 1, tried to make changes in spark-defaults.conf, but nothing changed in yarn ui. only 2 cores used. Then I found spark (history?) ui. I've updated main post with pictures. Now I'm totally lost. In spark ui 1 executer, 4 cores as expected. But why at yarn ui 2 cores used ?

Comment: It is a bug. If Spark UI shows 4 cores = RM UI should have 4+1(AM). I have 2+ years of Yarn experience, haven't seen such problem, it always shows correct number.

Comment: @Triffids Try running simple `bin/spark-shell --master yarn`  and see if RM UI has the same 2 cores.

Comment: I've found what was wrong in my config. I did not changed memory parameters. spark was able to get only 1 executer, because it was not enough memory to get second and third executers ... but yarn ui looks strange anyway, in yarn ui 1 container=1 vcpu. 
<br>
`spark.executor.cores 3

spark.executor.instances 2`

spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client 

yarn ui shows 4 cores. As I understand 1 app master + 3 executers.

spark ui shows 0 cores on driver and 6 cores on 3 executors

Answer (score 0):

If you want YARN shows you proper number of cores allocated to executors change value in capacity-scheduler.xml for:

```
yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator
```

from:

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator
```

to:

```
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
```

Otherwise it doesn't matter how many cores you ask for your executors, YARN will show you only one core per container.

Actually this config changes resource allocation behavior. More details: https://hortonworks.com/blog/managing-cpu-resources-in-your-hadoop-yarn-clusters/